# How do I convert from an OpenSSH key to PuTTY format in C#?

Tags: c#, putty, private-key

I have a key generated by SharpSSH in OpenSSH format.  How do I convert it to PuTTY format in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen) for how to use puttygen on linux.

You should be able to take the source code for this or the windows version and  and create a windows DLL if one is not available. Then you can pinvoke to access it.

I downloaded the sources from [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).